# Botão que sobrepõe todas as telas

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Como fazer um botão flutuante que sobrepõe todas as telas , principalmente as telas fora do aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

na imagem tem 2 exemplos de botões flutuantes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um float Button que funcione fora do app, você precisa trabalhar com **Service**, ele funciona como se fosse um BroadCast que trabalha sempre em background, ou seja, quando o APP está fechado ou em segundo plano.

Para criar o service, você precisa fazer algo de uma forma que crie a imagem que será o botão de float via códigos, exemplo:

```
public class BubbleNoteService extends Service {

    public static final String TAG = "BubbleNoteService";
    private static final int MOVE_THRESHOLD = 100;  // square of the threshold distance in pixels

    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private ViewGroup mBubble;
    private View mContent;

    private boolean mbExpanded = false;
    private boolean mbMoved = false;
    private int[] mPos = {0, -20};

    private static Spring sBubbleSpring;
    private static Spring sContentSpring;
    public static int sSpringTension = 200;
    public static int sSpringFriction = 20;

    public static void setSpringConfig() {
        SpringConfig config = sBubbleSpring.getSpringConfig();
        config.tension = sSpringTension;
        config.friction = sSpringFriction;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mBubble = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.bubble, null, false);

        mContent = mBubble.findViewById(R.id.content);
        mContent.setScaleX(0.0f);
        mContent.setScaleY(0.0f);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams contentParams = mContent.getLayoutParams();
        contentParams.width = Utils.getScreenWidth(this);
        contentParams.height = Utils.getScreenHeight(this) - getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.bubble_height);
        mContent.setLayoutParams(contentParams);

        mBubble.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mContent.setPivotX(mBubble.findViewById(R.id.bubble).getWidth() / 2);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    mBubble.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    mBubble.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = mPos[0];
        params.y = mPos[1];
        params.dimAmount = 0.6f;


        SpringSystem system = SpringSystem.create();
        SpringConfig springConfig = new SpringConfig(sSpringTension, sSpringFriction);

        sContentSpring = system.createSpring();
        sContentSpring.setSpringConfig(springConfig);
        sContentSpring.setCurrentValue(0.0);
        sContentSpring.addListener(new SpringListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
                float value = (float) spring.getCurrentValue();
                float clampedValue = (float) SpringUtil.clamp(value, 0.0, 1.0);
                mContent.setScaleX(value);
                mContent.setScaleY(value);
                mContent.setAlpha(clampedValue);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSpringAtRest(Spring spring) {
                mContent.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
                if (spring.currentValueIsApproximately(0.0)) {
                    hideContent();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSpringActivate(Spring spring) {
                mContent.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSpringEndStateChange(Spring spring) {

            }
        });

        sBubbleSpring = system.createSpring();
        sBubbleSpring.setSpringConfig(springConfig);
        sBubbleSpring.setCurrentValue(1.0);
        sBubbleSpring.addListener(new SpringListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
                double value = spring.getCurrentValue();
                params.x = (int) (SpringUtil.mapValueFromRangeToRange(value, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, mPos[0]));
                params.y = (int) (SpringUtil.mapValueFromRangeToRange(value, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, mPos[1]));
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mBubble, params);
                if (spring.isOvershooting() && sContentSpring.isAtRest()) {
                    sContentSpring.setEndValue(1.0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSpringAtRest(Spring spring) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSpringActivate(Spring spring) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSpringEndStateChange(Spring spring) {

            }
        });


        mBubble.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mbMoved = false;
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        showContent();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (mbMoved) return true;
                        if (! mbExpanded) {
                            mBubble.getLocationOnScreen(mPos);
                            mPos[1] -= Utils.getStatusBarHeight(BubbleNoteService.this);
                            params.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
                            params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
                            sBubbleSpring.setEndValue(0.0);
                        } else {
                            params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
                            params.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
                            sBubbleSpring.setEndValue(1.0);
                            sContentSpring.setEndValue(0.0);
                        }
                        mbExpanded = ! mbExpanded;
                        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mBubble, params);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int deltaX = (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        int deltaY = (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        params.x = initialX + deltaX;
                        params.y = initialY + deltaY;
                        if (deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY >= MOVE_THRESHOLD) {
                            mbMoved = true;
                            hideContent();
                            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mBubble, params);
                        }
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mWindowManager.addView(mBubble, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mBubble != null) {
            mWindowManager.removeView(mBubble);
        }
    }

    private void showContent() {
        mContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void hideContent() {
        mContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Com esse serviço criado, você ja tem a imagem (float button) e a captação de todos os movimentos dela no device.

Para controle do click no floatbutton, você deve ter uma chamada no onCreate de sua MainActivity, dessa forma:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BubbleNoteService.class);
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

E para controlar em background, você pode colocar no **onStop** ou **onDestroy**:

Segue abaixo alguns links de libs que controlam isso:

https://github.com/JustinScott/AppFloater

https://github.com/vickychijwani/BubbleNote

https://github.com/sezeryesiltas/chat-head-demo

https://github.com/callmekarthik/FBChatHeadExample

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79311)

Comment: Valeu pela dica Diego, alterei minha resposta.